# Using rewrite rule to access a view of a plugin from home page

Tags: plugins, rewrite-rules, front-end

I'm creating a plugin that has a view in front-end and i have a link in home page to access it:
`/wp-content/plugins/wp-test-plugin/public/partials/wp-test-plugin-public-display.php`.

But I want a rewrite rule to access it using a short url like:
`/wp-test-plugin`

My rewrite funnctions that doesn't work:

```
public function my_rewrite_roles() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $new_rules = array('^wp-test-plugin/?$' => 'wp-content/plugins/wp-test-plugin/public/partials/wp-test-plugin-public-display.php');
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    //return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Comment: What `wp-test-plugin-public-display.php` does? What do you mean with "it doesn't work? As it is, your rewrite rule is saying to WordPress: if someone requests `/wp-test-plugin` then serve a PHP file that is outside WordPress. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do? It seems to me that you are asking the wrong question and may be falling into a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I guess what you really want is to use that PHP file like a template or a template part, which is not waht rewrite rules does. Can you explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create / handle your endpoint and attempt to load your php if the file is readable. Note: you won't want to refresh the rewrite rules here but it'll make sure you can test quickly.

```
if (!class_exists('WPTestPluginEndpoint')):

    class WPTestPluginEndpoint
    {
        const ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME = '__my_test_plugin';

        // WordPress hooks

        public function init()
        {
            add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'add_query_vars'), 0);
            add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'sniff_requests'), 0);
            add_action('init', array($this, 'add_endpoint'), 0);
        }

        // Add public query vars
        public function add_query_vars($vars)
        {
            $vars[] = static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME;

            return $vars;
        }

        // Add API Endpoint

        public function add_endpoint()
        {
            $query_name = self::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME;
            add_rewrite_rule('^wp-test-plugin/?', "index.php?{$query_name}=1", 'top');

//////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////
// don't do this all the time!!!
//////////////////////////////////////
flush_rewrite_rules(false);
//////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////
        }

        // Sniff Requests

        public function sniff_requests()
        {
            global $wp;
            if (isset($wp->query_vars[ self::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME ])) {
                $this->handle_request(); // handle it
                exit;
            }
        }

        // Handle Requests

        protected function handle_request()
        {
            $public_display = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/wp-test-plugin/public/partials/wp-test-plugin-public-display.php';

            if( is_readable( $public_display )) {

                require $public_display;

            }
            else {

                wp_die("Can't find Render Page ". $public_display );

            }

            die(); // nothing to be done
        }
    }

    $wptept = new WPTestPluginEndpoint();
    $wptept->init();

endif; // WPTestPluginEndpoint
```

Comment: Just a tip, filter and actions should not be executed inside constructors. Constructors should not be doing any work, it should initialize

Comment: Fixed and the example has been updated... You're correct, that's usually the case for all languages.