# add_rewrite_rule issues

Tags: rewrite-rules

i usually add rewrite rules for custom pages like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^deal-purchase?','index.php?is_purchase_page=1&post_type=page','top');
```

However on a site im working on now, the above just redirects to the home page whereas if i create a custom post type and reference that:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^deal-purchase?','index.php?is_purchase_page=1&post_type=market','top');
```

it works. Anyone any ideas what might be causing the 1st code to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one works because `post_type=market` triggers the market post type archive.

Pages have no archive, so `post_type=page` in the first example doesn't point to a valid destination.

Rewrite rules have to ultimately result in a successful main query.

For a specific page, you could use `page_id` or `pagename`.

Comment: thanks for that! I'm actually not creating pages so no `page_id` exists. So what i do is set a query var and then return the template path to a php file. Is there a better way to directly point to a php file without creating a posttype to use in the rewrite rule?

Comment: check out [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162476/4771).