# Plugin as custom page

Tags: plugin-development

I'm begginer in wordpress (but not begginer in PHP) and I would like to make custom search page as plugin with this url www.example.tld/book-search. It would be simple page for searching books from library system (other database). I want that custom page editable only by editing php file (only way to delete the page is to remove plugin).

What is the easiest way to create this custom php page? I thought something like this would be possible but I have no luck finding solutions for it: create custom php page book_search.php and in plugin main file just say forward this url (www.example.tld/book-search) to this file.

I made this plugin in drupal and it was pretty easy (several lines of code to achieve this) so I'm hoping something similar would be possible in wordpress.

I would be gratefull for any tips

Comment: Do you envision it should integrate with site's theme of choice (big can of worms), or just be _completely_ custom page where your plugin produces 100% of page source?

Comment: it would be nice if it could integrate into theme :) or atleast it could integrate into my 1 custom theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your plugin have to **completely** control the output of the page, i.e. not taking into account the active theme or other installed plugins, than you can simply prevent WordPress handle that url.

For example:

```
add_action('init', function() {

  if (trim(add_query_arg(array()), '/') === 'book-search') {

     require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "pages/book-search.php"; 
     exit();
  }

});
```

[`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) is used above to obtain the current viewed url relative to home url.

What I do is require a specific php file from plugin folder if the viewed url is the one you're looking for.

That file, `pages/book-search.php` should contain **all** the code to ouput the content of the page.

If your aim is to integrate some content with active theme, than things ar more complex.

Look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162240/custom-pages-with-plugin/162476#162476) that explain how to create virtual pages with plugins.

In your case, using code in that answer you have to play with `setContent()` function to change what is shown.

An alternative is to use shortcodes, but in that case you can't choose the url.

Comment: Thanks for simple answer and for referencing another answer. I was hoping there is something easier :)

Answer (score 0):

The *common* options are the following:

1. Provide a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to use in page's content.
2. Implement as [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), unfortunately needs to be in theme, WP *really* doesn't like to let plugins do this.
3. Implement virtual page, for example with [endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

There are more, ranging from uncommon to outright exotic. But without getting too crazy you should probably try out one of these for starters.