# Virtual Pages plugins

Tags: customization, pages

I having hard time to make work the plugin [Virtual Pages](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/1efe17a8cb573e19c086) (WordPress plugin to ease the creation of virtual pages)

I did have edit to create a loop based on a query.

```
add_action( 'gm_virtual_pages', function( $controller ) {
/* Creating virtuals pages for companies */ 
$args = array( 'post_type' => array('companies',), 'post_status' => array('publish',), );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

   // Creations des pages
   $controller->addPage( new \GM\VirtualPages\Page( '/companies/'.$the_query->post->post_name.'/about' ) )
     ->setTitle( 'About Us' )
     ->setContent( get_the_content() )
     ->setTemplate( 'custom-page.php' );

endwhile;
endif;
```

`custom-page.php` is in the child theme folder, and the controller in the root theme. I did have tried to put all the file in the parent theme, but it's the same.

I took the [exact code download](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/1efe17a8cb573e19c086), minus one virgule at the section "how tu use".

```
$controller->addPage( new \GM\VirtualPages\Page( "/custom/page" ) )
 ->setTitle( 'My First Custom Page' )
 ->setContent( '<p>Hey, this is my first cutom virtual page!</p>' );
 ->setTemplate( 'custom-page.php' )
```

Line 3, the is no ; at the end. Rather than that everything is the same. I check the download code and the published / commented code.

- `$Title` is returning "About US"
- `$content` is returning the post content but
- `$Template` is returning `page.php`, and if im right, it should return `custom-page.php`, or at least, if it's an inclusion, i should see the content of `custom-page.php` in the page.

I followed all process, read everything, but still not working. Anyone as any hint to fix this, before me passing to another method ?

Comment: Out of interest, why aren't you using natural permalinks for your custom post type?

Comment: Because the main objective is to create a Website generated  once a child template is activated. The content to fill pages are directly coming from a custom post type. 
Ex : I create a company, from a custom post type, and from there, a full company website is generated, with virtual pages without having to create post page.

Comment: Have you read the affiliated [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162476/22534)? The explanation there is pretty good. Aside from that the semicolon has to be after the last method call, the way you show it in your question you should get an error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of that plugin and I can confirm there was an issue.

It was in the [`GM\VirtualPages\TemplateLoader::init();`](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/1efe17a8cb573e19c086#file-templateloader-php-L4) method.

Issue was caused by an untested switch from `array_merge` to `wp_parse_args`.

They are similar, but I would have to inverse order of arguments moving from one to the other. Shame on me.

I fixed that in the Gist ([source](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/1efe17a8cb573e19c086#file-templateloader-php-L8)) now it should work.

Comment: Strange. 
no i have an error installing the plugin. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ..../wp-content/plugins/gm-virtuals-pages/gm-virtual-pages.php on line 1

Comment: @groupe-wibi that file has not been modified at all. Are you sure you have PHP 5.3+?

Comment: Nop. 5.2+ ;( Can i adapt it ?

Comment: @GroupeWibi First of all you need to remove all namespaces and add a prefix to all classes and interface names (of course, that suffix have to be added everywhere in the file where names appear). After that you need to replace anonymous functions with named ones in `gm-virtual-pages.php`. BTW note that [PHP 5.2 reached its end of life in 2011](http://php.net/eol.php)(!) it means it's **unsecure**, far **slower** than newer versions and, as you experienced, **feature missing**. I **strongly** suggest you to change hosting: your are paying for garbage if they do not offer 5.4+ PHP version.