# Integrate product feed API in Woocommerce

Tags: api

I want to integrate an API for automatically import products from a 3rd party.

I have the API for that . API documentation says as follows.,

> We update inventory every 24 hours!
>
> The API request must be in the following form:**
>
> http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/api.php?apikey=myAPIkeyHere

The API response is a JSON string containing all the listings (>55.000)

You can set the optional variable debug=1 when you are testing, this will force that the response from the API contain only 50 listings and you have unlimited daily requests.

The only request method available is GET

**Example: API Request (with CURL)**

```
$ch = curl_init('http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/api.php?apikey=myAPIkeyHere')
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Example: API Response (JSON)**

```
{
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "message":"Results have been extracted",
    "results":[{
                "post_title":"1984 AQUASPORT 222 FT W96 YAMAHA",
                "post_name":"1984-aquasport-22-2-ft-w96-ya",
                "post_content":"Nice boat 1984 aquasport 22.2 ft c.c 1996 yamaha 200 hp runs good.",
                "post_category":"By Owner",
                "price":"52000",
                "location":"Miami, FL",
                "stock":"952481",
                "year":"2007",
                "images":[
                          "http:\/\/boatexportusa.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/api\/get-image.php?src=fakesrc\/00o0o_7TGyKJXFMp9_600x450.jpg",
                          "http:\/\/boatexportusa.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/api\/get-image.php?src=fakesrc\/00o0o_7TGyKJXFMp9_600x450.jpg"
                         ],
                "cond":"new",
                "size":"27'",
                "make":"SeaRay",
                "model":"S300",
                "hours":"330",
                "propulsion":"Power",
                "addedtime":"2015-03-23"
                }]
}
```

I am blind stuck on how to proceed

How should i integrate this API with the Wocommerce Products to automatically get synced

**UPDATE :**

Image is not getting stored , I use the following code

```
'post_images' => $data[ 'images' ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar problem to [create posts from an API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211972/84219) and [programmatically generating posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211344/84219).

Essentially just parse the JSON into an array, grab the fields you need, and create the post/product. You most likely need to pull the images as well.

You should also consider if the post already exists in your database and how/where you want the extra metadata to live like; price, stock, year, hours, etc...

**JSON PARSE**

```
$response = '{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Results have been extracted","results":[{"post_title":"1984 AQUASPORT 222 FT W96 YAMAHA","post_name":"1984-aquasport-22-2-ft-w96-ya","post_content":"Nice boat 1984 aquasport 22.2 ft c.c 1996 yamaha 200 hp runs good.","post_category":"By Owner","price":"52000","location":"Miami, FL","stock":"952481","year":"2007","images":["http:\/\/boatexportusa.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/api\/get-image.php?src=fakesrc\/00o0o_7TGyKJXFMp9_600x450.jpg","http:\/\/boatexportusa.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/api\/get-image.php?src=fakesrc\/00o0o_7TGyKJXFMp9_600x450.jpg"],"cond":"new","size":"27\'","make":"SeaRay","model":"S300","hours":"330","propulsion":"Power","addedtime":"2015-03-23"}]}';

// decode the json

$json = json_decode($response, true);

// loop through the results

if( ! empty($json[ 'results' ])) {
    foreach($json[ 'results' ] as $data) {

        // gather data you need, make sure to sanitize it

        $post_data = array(
            'post_title'   => $data[ 'post_title' ],
            'post_name'    => $data[ 'post_name' ],
            'post_content' => $data[ 'post_content' ],
            'post_date'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_status'  => 'publish', 
            'post_author'  => 1,
        );

        // create product or post and return the new ID

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, $wp_error);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I would recommend putting this into a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). That way you can turn it on or off and keep it separate from your main theme. Use something like [WPPB.me](http://wppb.me) to generate a basic plugin.

When the plugin [activates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), schedule a [WP Cron task](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to run `daily`.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_daily_event');
}

add_action('my_daily_event', 'do_this_daily');

function do_this_daily() {
    // pull api data every day
}
```

Since the [WP Cron](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/) is a fake cron it might be best to hook your API pull in the [shutdown](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/shutdown) hook or avoid cron and trigger it from an admin [option page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages). Either way [TechCrunch WP Asynchronous Tasks](https://github.com/techcrunch/wp-async-task/) could help offload the processing power to another task.

Once you've pulled the new data you'll want to figure out a way to uniquely identify the product so you don't duplicate it in the database. Check to see if it exists and if it does then update it. If not, make a new one.

[update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to set it, [WP_Meta_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) to see if it exists. Or check by title:

```
if (null == get_page_by_title($title) && empty(get_posts(array('name' => $slug))))
```

If it helps, make a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) to capture the product data and generate them on a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) using a [custom query](https://generatewp.com/wp_query/).

Everything outside of what I answered you could google, try it out, and ask new questions when you run into issues.

Comment: First of all thanks @jgraup .

Can you explain me step by step like which file i should edit in which location and what code . 

Sorry for looking silly , i am just a beginner mate .

Comment: Your above json parse code inserts the data successfully . But , if i add url instead of product datas like $response = 'feed url'; it doesnt work . aslo tried $url = 'http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/api.php?apikey=mykey'; then $response='$url'; this also not helped . can you tell me how to add feed url in this json parse code you gave . aslo how to check for duplicate entries

Comment: also tried following but nothing came up                                                    `$ch = curl_init('url/myapikey') 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
if( ! empty($json[ 'results' ])) {
    foreach($json[ 'results' ] as $data) {
         $post_data = array(
                'post_title' => $data[ 'post_title' ],
                'post_name' => $data[ 'post_name' ],
                   );           
       $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, $wp_error);
    }
}`

Comment: I echo and got the following error "Requested Range not satisfiable"

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get might be better to use than CURL - good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot mate . Worked perfectly :-) If you dont mind can you suggest me for avoiding duplicate entries

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211972/84219 - there is a check in  there for duplicate titles. That is one way, another is to add meta data on a new post you create and search the DB before creating a new post with the same meta data. It's up to you to determine what is unique to your data.

Comment: Will look into that mate . Thanks for the reference

Comment: Except images everything works fine , For image i use `'post_images' => $data[ 'images' ],` whether is that wrong ? actually what happens was image not even got stored

Comment: Updated in the question mate

Comment: also by default in WP i can't found anything like post_images in DB ?!?! what would be the correct one for the featured image

Comment: You need to sideload the images. that means they need to be downloaded to your server, then attached to the post.

Comment: can you guide me on doing that please

Comment: Done :  [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213745/insert-featured-image-from-feed)

Comment: Image management would be interesting - to save and use local image...