# Insert Featured image from Feed

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, woocommerce-offtopic, feed

I am importing products through a feed programmatically as follows:

```
$request = wp_remote_get('myapiurl');
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

// decode the json

$json = json_decode($response, true);

// loop through the results

if( ! empty($json[ 'results' ])) {
    foreach($json[ 'results' ] as $data) {

        // gather data you need, make sure to sanitize it

        $post_data = array(
              'post_title' => $data[ 'post_title' ],
                'post_name' => $data[ 'post_name' ],
                'post_content' => $data[ 'post_content' ],
                'post_category' => $data[ 'post_category' ],
                '_price' => $data[ 'price' ],
                'post_location' => $data[ 'location' ],
                'post_stock' => $data[ 'stock' ],
                'post_year' => $data[ 'year' ],
                'post_images' => $data[ 'images' ],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'product',
        );

        // create product or post and return the new ID

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, $wp_error);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the image is not inserting as the featured image.

Kindly help me please

**UPDATE :**

**Example: API Response (JSON)**

```
{
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "message":"Results have been extracted",
    "results":[{
                "post_title":"1984 AQUASPORT 222 FT W96 YAMAHA",
                "post_name":"1984-aquasport-22-2-ft-w96-ya",
                "post_content":"Nice boat 1984 aquasport 22.2 ft c.c 1996 yamaha 200 hp runs good.",
                "post_category":"By Owner",
                "price":"52000",
                "location":"Miami, FL",
                "stock":"952481",
                "year":"2007",
                "images":[
                          "http:\/\/boatexportusa.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/api\/get-image.php?src=fakesrc\/00o0o_7TGyKJXFMp9_600x450.jpg",
                          "http:\/\/boatexportusa.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/api\/get-image.php?src=fakesrc\/00o0o_7TGyKJXFMp9_600x450.jpg"
                         ],
                "cond":"new",
                "size":"27'",
                "make":"SeaRay",
                "model":"S300",
                "hours":"330",
                "propulsion":"Power",
                "addedtime":"2015-03-23"
                }]
}
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

```
[post_images] => Array
(
[0] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00k0k_l1jwqDulnwk_600x450.jpg
[1] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00k0k_l1jwqDulnwk_600x450.jpg
[2] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00303_cALZYkakJx2_600x450.jpg
[3] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/01515_5nEeIcoBGot_600x450.jpg
)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

*Echo for : 'images' => $data[ 'images' ] :*

```
[images] => Array
(
[0] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00d0d_3Qnz0HTaTVP_600x450.jpg
[1] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00d0d_3Qnz0HTaTVP_600x450.jpg
[2] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00202_apLgMytA6Fo_600x450.jpg
[3] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00J0J_2rxcE4rqK3h_600x450.jpg
[4] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00t0t_4PKqbSme4FE_600x450.jpg
[5] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00q0q_jbVdZ1mNi9R_600x450.jpg
[6] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00r0r_l2XOi3b8tML_600x450.jpg
[7] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00j0j_cHeK38ceFIG_600x450.jpg
[8] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00D0D_dqcnZzF1Msl_600x450.jpg
[9] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00606_aWYjRYKgX0g_600x450.jpg
[10] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00707_dfM9vlGIvcS_600x450.jpg
[11] => http://boatexportusa.com/wp-content/plugins/api/get-image.php?src=fakesrc/00U0U_jINezkwXHhY_600x450.jpg
)
```

*Echo for $image_ids in your code :*

```
Array
(
[0] => 0
[1] => 0
[2] => 0
[3] => 0
[4] => 0
[5] => 0
[6] => 0
[7] => 0
[8] => 0
[9] => 0
[10] => 0
[11] => 0
)
```

Comment: @jgraup updated in question

Comment: You  mean the one which i updated now in the question as Update 1 : ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the images onto your server and into the library. From that point you will be able to attach them to the post. You can only have [1 featured image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) so this needs to be adjusted to set the featured once but still download all the images and [attach them to the post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id).

I'm using [media_sideload_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) in this example but you could use [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) (there is another example on that page).

```
// the new post has been created
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, $wp_error);

// now we'll deal with the images

$image_ids = array();

foreach($data[ 'images' ] as $inx => $url) {

    // add external image to our library
    $src = media_sideload_image(rawurldecode($url), $post_id, NULL, 'src');

    // convert to attachment src -> ID -> post
    $attach_id = attachment_url_to_postid($src);

    // grab the id so we can add to the post when we're done
    $image_ids[] = $attach_id;

    // access to attachment post
    // $attach_post = get_post($attach_id);

    // set the image's parent id to the post
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $attach_id, 'post_parent' => $post_id));

    if($inx === 0) {
        // add the first image as the post's featured image
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id, true);
    }
}

// add the ids onto the post's meta to use later -- store as simple string
add_post_meta($post_id, '_images', implode(',', $image_ids), true);
```

> This code has not been tested

---

`post_images` is not a property of [WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) so they need to be associated another way. Also many of those other properties should be added using [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) instead of trying to add on the post itself - take a look at [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: So post_images is correct for featured images wright? that need not need to be changed wright?

Comment: also ,  i need to add the code above `// create product or post and return the new ID` or below that

Comment: Thanks , So , whats the proper Member variable for featured images

Comment: what about `$images => $data[ 'images' ],`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply mate , i was out of work for few days . Just back . This code returns error so i changed as you said to wp_insert_attachment . then it results same as earlier without images . Also if the image gets locally downloaded then it should be on media gallery wright? but media gallery is empty

Comment: Look at the update in my question mate !!!