# WordPress thinks my custom route is a 404

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error

I created a plugin that sets up a custom route and then loads a template file for that url. Everything works fine, except that WordPress seems to think it's a 404 even though it's correctly rendering my template.

For instance it says 404 in the document title and an `error404` class is added to `<body>`

The custom url is domain.com/path/:id where `:id` is a dynamic value corresponding to a post id, so the URL could be domain.com/path/275. In the example below `some_id` is used as the post id variable.

Here's a reduced version of my plugin:

```
<?php

class MyPlugin {
  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'add_response_endpoint') );
    add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'add_response_template') );
  }

  public function add_response_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
      '^path/([0-9]+)/?',
      'index.php?pagename=my_custom_url&some_id=$matches[1]',
      'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_tag('%some_id%', '([^&]+)');
  }

  public function add_response_template($template) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'pagename' ) === 'my_custom_url' ) {
      $template = trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'templates/custom-page-template.php';
    }

    return $template;
  }
}

new MyPlugin();
```

Am I missing something here? Or should I start looking for this bug elsewhere?

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: Yes. Flushed the rewrite rules. Both manually and in the plugin's activation hook.

Comment: Rewrite rules have to result in a successful main query. If `my_custom_url` is not the slug of an actual page, you will get a 404. If `some_id` is a valid post ID, then [set the correct native query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) with that ID so the query succeeds.

Comment: That's just not always an option. For instance, if I want to provide a "My profile" frontend page for my users where they can update basic information about themselves. There's no post associated with such a page, but I still need a URL for it. In any case, I figured out a solution and posted my answer below.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162476/4771) of an approach that short-circuits the query parsing phase and doesn't produce a query that's just doomed to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually setting `is_404 = false;` fixed my issue. However I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. I tried using the `pre_get_posts` filter instead without any luck.

Anyway, for anyone else in the same boat, you can do this to get rid of the 404 state:

```
public function add_response_template($template) {
  global $wp_query;
  if ( 'my_custom_url' === get_query_var( 'pagename' ) ) {
    $wp_query->is_404 = false;
    $template = trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'templates/custom-page-template.php';
  }

  return $template;
}
```

And to update the document title (The stuff inside `<title>` in the `<head>` section) here's a snippet for making that work nicely too.

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function($title_arr) {
  if ( 'my_custom_url' === get_query_var('pagename') ) {
    $title_arr['title'] = "Document title for my custom route";
  }

  return $title_arr;
}, 10, 1 );
```

If anyone knows of a better way please let me know.

Comment: `is_404 = false;` is not working for me the status still 404 but `status_header(200);` works!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found custom routes in WP mature enough.
I suggest you use any of the 3 routes solutions mentioned in Timber docs.
https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/guides/routing/

if you use Upstatement library (https://github.com/Upstatement/routes) you would do:

```
Routes::map('info/:name/page/:pg', function($params){
    //make a custom query based on incoming path and run it...
    $query = 'posts_per_page=3&post_type='.$params['name'].'&paged='.intval($params['pg']);

    //load up a template which will use that query
    Routes::load('archive.php', null, $query, 200);
});
```

See the 200 in Routes::load, that sends the proper header.

If you need something more versatile use Rareloop router https://github.com/Rareloop/router