# How to use a frontend URL with a Plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, html

I want to use a URL to display content in the frontend. For example

- domain.tld/?myplugin&confirmey=KEY&mail=MAIL

But i don´t know the way(s?) to do it. For example i have a user that clicks on a confirm link in an E-Mail and i want to show him a page with some text.

- Must exist a real page in WordPres?
- Can i include a frontend.php in the existing Content-Area of the Theme to display my text?
- Are there other solutions?

I don't want a user of the plugin to manually add a page or even add code to their themes functions.php

Comment: do you want your content to appear in the context of the current theme?

Comment: Use https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule to make any link you require.

Comment: Yes. As an example in the layout from a post/page within the current theme. But only with my content. @Milo

Comment: @jgraup Do you have a small example? Isn´t the rewrite rule there to change an existing url to another? But what should my existing url be to show code in the frontend without having an existing page in WordPress?

Comment: The rewrite rule allows you to change any structure to another structure.  Perhaps you just need to run your methods when it's time to run the parse_query. I've made several examples but I can't remember the functions off the top of my head. Just do a search...

Comment: Okay, i give up. The only results i get is to reffer to an existing page. But i dont have one. Perhaps im not using the correct keywords in my search. I don´t know..... Don´t missunderstand me - i don´t want a ready-to-use solution. But the add_rewrite_rule actions don´t helps in my search..... And im searching for hours now..... @jgraup

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162476/4771) might help you. the problem is that theme files need a main query object, so you need a real or "virtual" page. many plugins solve this by creating pages as placeholders, then run plugin code in content filter or shortcode.

Comment: Puh, much informations. Its a good solution, thanks. @Milo Another question that would make it easier: Is there a way to add a real page that is not shown anywhere - even for the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution I was looking for. I want to leave it here if someone else need this. With this solution the user of the Plugin don´t need to do anything (create a page or copy files).

So first we add the action to WP

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_url' );
```

Here we are looking for our URL

```
function check_confirm_url() {
    return false !== strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/myplugin/confirm' );
}
```

Here we add the content if the URL matches

```
function check_url() {
    if( check_confirm_url() ) {
        add_filter( 'the_posts', 'confirm_page' );
    }
}
```

This is the page and where we can do all the stuff

```
function confirm_page( $posts ) {

    //do all the stuff here

    $posts = null;
    $post = new stdClass();
    $post->post_content = "Confirm Content";
    $post->post_title = "Confirm";
    $post->post_type = "page";
    $post->comment_status = "closed";
    $posts[] = $post;
    return $posts;
}
```

If we now enter this URL, we have our own Page and can work with the GET data.

```
http://domain.tld/myplugin/confirm?mail=MAILADRESS&key=KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

> Must exist a real page in WordPres?

Yes, you need to create a page, but it doesn't have to have any content.

Let's say you created a new page named 'Confirmation message'. The URL would be `http://example.com/confirmation-message`.

Now add the following to the `functions.php` of your theme:

```
/**
 * Adds a confirmation message to the content of a page.
 * 
 * @param   string  $content    The current content of the page.
 * @return  string              The new content of the page.
 */
function show_confirmation_message($content) {

    // Don't add message if 'myplugin', 'confirmkey' and 'mail' are not in the URL.
    if (!isset($_GET['myplugin']) || empty($_GET['confirmkey']) || empty($_GET['mail'])) {
        return $content;
    }

    // Don't add message if we're not on a page and not in the main query.
    if( !is_page() || !is_main_query() ) {
        return $content;
    }

    // Add the logic to show a confirmaiton message here... 
    $content.= 'This is the confirmation message.';

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'show_confirmation_message');
```

Now, if you go to:

`http://example.com/confirmation-message?myplugin&confirmkey=KEY&mail=MAIL` you should see the confirmation message.

Comment: I dont want a user of the plugin to manually add a page or even add code to their themes functions.php - For the own Website its a nice idea, thanks.

Comment: Aha. The only thing I can think of is the way that WooCommerce does it. If it detects that the page isn't there, it offers to create it for you.