# Supress listing of virtual pages

Tags: pages

I create virtual pages for my plugin in [this way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242814/how-to-use-a-frontend-url-with-a-plugin/243589#243589).

```
function confirm_page() {
    $posts = null;
    $post = new stdClass();
    $post->post_content = confirm_page_content();
    $post->post_title = 'Confirm';
    $post->post_type = 'page';
    $post->comment_status = 'closed';
    $posts[] = $post;
    return $posts;
}
```

How can i supress the listing of this page in Widgets like the "Recent Posts Widget"? And why is it listed there?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? How/where is this function being called?

Comment: Have a look at the link in the first sentence (this way) :)

Comment: remove the filter that hooks `confirm_page` after it runs on the main query. any query that runs on your confirm page will call `the_posts` and will therefore have your page added to those results.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use the filter in the Recents

from [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_recent_posts/widget/) WP_Widget_Recent_Posts::widget

```
$r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
    'posts_per_page'      => $number,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
) ) );
```

Best way will be, to add a category to the post your submit from frontend.

```
add_filter('widget_posts_args', 'wpse_244383');

function wpse_244383(){
    return array(
        'posts_per_page'      => $number,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'cat' => '-12' // term_id of the category you want to exclude
    );
}
```

Comment: But why is my ->PAGE<- listed in the recent ->POSTS<- widget?

Comment: Add post_type=>'post' and remove category exclude, there no post type set in the recent posts query !!?