# Is it possible to generate a page without create in the admin?

Tags: php, pages

I need some pages for tracking purposes. I have some forms and depending of what city and course the user chooses, it redirects to the corresponding page (the url need to be like domain.com/course-city). 
Is there a way to do this without create this pages? Ou create them dynamically

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162240/custom-pages-with-plugin/162476#162476

Answer (score 1):

You can create pages via techniques similar to this https://clicknathan.com/web-design/automatically-create-pages-wordpress/ . That might give you the basics of the code needed to create a page dynamically.

The question is 'when' you will do this. You will need to tie your code into some action that corresponds to the 'when' you want the page to be created. The example above shows how to create pages when a sub-site is created in a multisite site (say an 'about' page that you want to be included on all sub-sites when a new sub-site is created).

The link above (and many similar links if you ask the googles) might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for tracking purposes, use a regular Page but redirect using a query string that includes the city and course. So if you create example.com/course/ as your Page, you can redirect the visitors who have submitted the form to

`example.com/course/?city=paris&course=basketweaving`

Then set up event tracking in Google Analytics so that whenever "city" and "course" are in the query string, it records an event. For example, record an event named "form submission" with action "paris" and label "basketweaving". This will be easier if you're using Google Tag Manager, which can fire events based on the URL. If the `example.com/course/` Page should only be shown to visitors who complete a form, you'll want to set up a Page Template which checks for "city" and "course" in the query string. If those are missing, you can redirect them to one of your forms or wherever you like. That way only the visitors who've already provided information will see the course page. You can also create conditional content in the Page Template so for example `if "city == Paris"` you show an Eiffel Tower excursion, etc.